# Sending audio with PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm using PPT 2007 on Vista.

My presentation has an audio file.  However, when I send the preso via email, the audio is not included.

What to do?

Answer (score 2):

Go to save as and click the down arrow and choose Save options

[image]

Next, click Advanced and scroll down to where it says "Link sounds with file size greater than:

Change this to 50000KB (the maximum it allows).

[image]

If your file is bigger than this, you may be out of luck :S or, use audio editing tools and split it, then in Powerpoint you can time it to start the other - but I am assuming it is under 50MB and I won't get in to that!

Original (and wrong, it is changed in 2007 / since the last time I used PowerPoint!)

I am guessing you did a direct link to the audio file and did not embed it inside of the PPT file.

Try sending the original .MP3, .WAV (or other) extension along with the PPT file or embedding it directly in to the document.

Comment: How do you embed it into the document?  I use insert/sound to add it to my PPT.

Comment: Im unsure, I only know what the problem is... I haven't used Power Point in about 5 years! Give me a few minutes and I will start it up and take a few screenshots for you then edit my original post

Answer (score 0):

And BTW, your sound files must be .wav
Go here for the full answer:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint/HA012303071033.aspx